# Run time exception when using Bloomberg BLPSubscribe in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I get a random run-time error when trying to get back 4 fields for a list of stocks. Call fails for random stocks and changing the fields subscribed to has not made a difference.
This is  the detailed error text:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005) #N/A Fld

And this is the code.

```
Dim bbgdata As new BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData
bbgdata.BLPSubscribe(sec, Array("PX LAST", "CUR_MKT_CAP", "3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", "VOLUME_AVG_90D"))
```

Comment: #N/A Fld means that one of the field is not valid for one (or all of) the given securities. You can try a BDP formula in excel with the same values to see which ticker/field is the problem.

Comment: @assylias Call with same data set works after I restart my vba application. I batched my calls and the failure is not so intermittent. I get the same error when I try without signing into BLP API.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Comment: I'll be hitting live help first thing tomorrow. I was just making sure it's not my code (I'm a vba newbie)

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to write out the results to a sheet instead of caching it in objects.

```
bbgdata = bbgDataControl.BLPSubscribe(seclist, Array("PX_CLOSE_1D", "PX LAST", "CUR_MKT_CAP", "3MTH_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", "VOLUME_AVG_90D"))
dataSheet.Range("BBG").Resize(UBound(bbgdata) + 1, UBound(bbgdata, 2) + 1) = bbgdata
```

Previously I was doing putting data in objects like:

```
For i = 0 To ub
  Dim bbgData as new BBGData
  bbgData.lastClose = bbgdata(i,0) 'etc.
next i
```